# how pass result from alertDialog to onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-activity, sdk

I have Activity_A an Activity_B.
I use onActivityResult and i have a problem:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras)
>   }} to activity {com.example.sellcar/com.example.sellcar.View_Offer}:
>   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0

I guess that I can not pass this way 'result' from alertDialog to onActivityResult.
I do not know how to solve this problem :/
Please help

**Activity_A:**

```
bBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this,Activity_B.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 3);

            }
        });
...
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                String pId = data.getStringExtra("MyData");

Toast.makeText(Activity_A.this,pId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
    }
```

**Activity_B:**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(View_Sell.this);
    builder.setTitle("UWAGA !").setMessage("blablabla");

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {       
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                                                                            
       String ostatnioDodanaSprzedaz="XYZ";
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.putExtra("MyData", ostatnioDodanaSprzedaz);
       setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
       onBackPressed();                                         
 } });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NO",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                               
 } });  

AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
ad.show();
```

Comment: I tried to use the finish () instead onBackPressed() but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
onBackPressed();
```

on:

```
if (getParent() == null) {
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
} else {
    getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
}
finish();
```

Comment: it's strange, because, I tried your code and it normally works for me

Comment: sory, it works :) it was also another error. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Observer pattern.

First, create an Interface in the Activity class itself:

```
public interface ResultListener {
        void onResultSet(String text);
    }
```

Then, create an object of `ResultListener` globally:

```
ResultListener = rl;
```

Implement the `onResultSet(String text)` method inside the onCreate method:

```
rl = new ResultListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPositiveResult(String text) {
                Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
```

Next, create the `AlertDialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("UWAGA !").setMessage("blablabla");

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {       
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                                                                            
       String ostatnioDodanaSprzedaz="XYZ";
       tl.onResultSet(ostatnioDodanaSprzedaz);
      // onBackPressed();                                         
 } });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NO",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                               
 } });  
    builder.show();
```

Here's how the final code will look:

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            ResultListener rl;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

                rl = new ResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPositiveResult(String text) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("UWAGA !").setMessage("blablabla");
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {       
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                                                                            
                       String ostatnioDodanaSprzedaz="XYZ";
                       rl.onResultSet(ostatnioDodanaSprzedaz);
                      // onBackPressed();                                         
                 } });

             builder.setNegativeButton("NO",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                               
                 } });  

             builder.show();

        } //onCreate closed

        public interface ResultListener {
                void onResultSet(String text);
        }

} //MainActivity Class closed
```